# Access to mobx-state-tree-action not from a FC component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, mobx-state-tree

I am learning to use the Mob-x-state tree in my pet project. And I have one problem:

I need to handle websocket events with my store like this:

```js
const {
  AccountsStore
} = useStore();
blablalbalba
  socket.onopen = function () {
    AccountsStore.handleWsStart();
  };
```

I am trying to use  AccountsStore.handleWsStart(); from my store:

```js
.actions(self => ({
    // note the `({`, we are returning an object literal
    handleWsStart() {
      self.isFetching = true;
    }
```

And have this issue:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

I understand what I am doing wrong, Can you tell me how I can access mobx-state-tree-action, not from an FC component or another way to handle WS events to store?